# How to output objects javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var markers = [
        {
          coords:{lat:  14.5858544, lng: 120.9763816},
        }
      ];
```

Hi everyone, how do I output the lat and lng? 
I can't seem to access them. I have tried

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = markers[0].coords

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  markers['coords'][0]['lat'];
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `markers[0].coords.lat`

Comment: object directly can't be displayed ,you can display value of  member of object using 'object.member_name'

Answer (score 2):

`markers[0].coords.lat`

or

`markers[0]['coords']['lat']`

Full documentation about this subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

The way you access different types is wrong. Try this:

```js
var markers = [
  {
    coords: {
      lat:  14.5858544,
      lng: 120.9763816
    },
  }
];

// To get lat
console.log(markers[0].coords.lat) // 14.5858544
// To get lng
console.log(markers[0].coords.lat) // 120.9763816
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var markers = [
        {
          coords:{lat:  14.5858544, lng: 120.9763816},
        }
      ];
      
function a(){
document.getElementById("demo_lat").innerHTML = markers[0].coords.lat;
document.getElementById("demo_lng").innerHTML = markers[0].coords.lng;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo_lat"></p>
<p id="demo_lng"></p>
<button onclick="a()">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your HTML

```
 var markers = [{
     coords: {
         lat: 14.5858544,
         lng: 120.9763816
     },
 }];
```

You can do either:

```
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = markers[0].coords.lat;
document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = markers[0].coords.lng;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = markers[0]['coords']['lat'];
document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = markers[0]['coords']['lng'];
```

To print them on console

```
 console.log(markers[0].coords.lat)
 console.log(markers[0].coords.lng)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lat and lng like this:

```js
var markers = [
        {
          coords:{lat:  14.5858544, lng: 120.9763816},
        }
      ];
      console.log( markers[0].coords.lat)
       console.log( markers[0].coords.lng)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var markers = [
    {
        coords: {lat:  14.5858544, lng: 120.9763816},
    }
];

document.getElementById(`demo`).innerHTML = `lat: ${markers[0].coords.lat}<br>lng: ${markers[0].coords.lng}`;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const getKeyOfObject = (key) => markers.map(item => 
  item.coords[key]).join('')

  getKeyOfObject('lat') // 14.5858544
```

---

Answer (score 0):

- The first approach only prints the Object `coords` instead of `lat` and `lng`.
- The second approach is trying to access an attribute called `coords` which doesn't exist.

**With that scenario, you can use [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):**

*This snippet loops over the possible markers*

```js
var markers = [{
  coords: {
    lat: 14.5858544,
    lng: 120.9763816
  },
}];

markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  var { lat, lng } = marker.coords; //Destructuring Assignment.
  console.log(lat, '-', lng);
});
```